# Spring 5 boilerplate project unable to run

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Im trying a tutorial on Spring 5 and I tried to create a Spring Boot project via [start.spring.io](http://start.spring.io) with default metadata.

Import it in Spring Tools Suite

```
Version: 3.9.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 201712210947
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.2 (4.7.2)
```

when i run via Spring Boot app, I recieve this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/framework/AopProxyUtils
at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.addApplicationListener(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:105)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.<init>(EventPublishingRunListener.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopProxyUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 14 more
```

So I put the dependencies in pom.xml, heres my updated pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-expression -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.4</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

When I try to run with the updated pom.xml,

```
15:33:01.349 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar, 
..
15:33:01.353 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:70)
```

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T15:58:13+08:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You are using Spring boot 1.5 (which is designed for Spring 4.3.x) and expect it to work with Spring 5. That isn't going to work. Never mix versions of a framework. If you want to use Spring 5 use Spring Boot 2 (which isn't final yet).

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, thanks for the info. i removed the version and rely on the starter-parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide information to reproduce your problem, so this is what I tried...

1. From SPRING INITIALIZR page I downloaded demo.zip
2. I built it using `mvn clean install`
3. I run application from same folder using `java -jar target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and that's it

build has to finish with success:

```
$ mvn clean install

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 13.346 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-02T09:02:15+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/314M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

log:

```
$ java -jar target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

2018-02-02 09:02:27.556  INFO 18588 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on CZCHOWN5019295 with PID 18588 (C:\betlista\DGF_MDM\tmp\demo\target\demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by msuska in c:\betlista\DGF_MDM\tmp\demo)
2018-02-02 09:02:27.560  INFO 18588 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-02-02 09:02:27.647  INFO 18588 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@255316f2: startup date [Fri Feb 02 09:02:27 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-02 09:02:28.551  INFO 18588 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-02-02 09:02:28.578  INFO 18588 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 1.571 seconds (JVM running for 2.332)
2018-02-02 09:02:28.579  INFO 18588 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@255316f2: startup date [Fri Feb 02 09:02:27 CET 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-02-02 09:02:28.581  INFO 18588 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

my versions of Java and Maven:

```
$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00)
Maven home: c:\betlista\progs\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_74, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: c:\java\jdk1.8.0_74\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"

$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
```

initial pom.xml dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Quick check - to remove all additional spring dependencies fixed the problem.

In other words I removed all `<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>` because it should be there because of Spring Boot, so very likely incompatible versions...

You can investigate further with `mvn dependency:tree`. It seems Spring Boot is using Spring 4.3.14, not 5.0.3 as you added...

To address you original issue - with `AopProxyUtils`, it is in spring-aop, which is in spring-boot-starter-aop and also in spring-boot-starter-web or spring-boot-starter-data-jpa you already have...

Comment: do you think this is os level issue? or maven, gradle, i have clean installation but still having exceptions.

Comment: I updated the answer with few details, please check. Without more info it's difficult to guess. Are you building from command line?

Comment: i added my maven version installation, yes, the exception is consistent from command line.

Comment: Hi, I can confirm, that when I added all your dependencies I can see that NPE in `BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:60)` = exactly as you have, so it's caused by dependencies you added... Try to add one by one...

Comment: This is just very simple mistake, the exception was very misleading. i tried to delete .m2/repo and redownload the dependencies. Its now working. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to test Spring 5 using Spring Boot today, you have to pick "Spring Boot 2.0.0 RC1" in http://start.spring.io/